# Query to determine if items have tax

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

Item

- ID
- Name

Item taxes

- ID
- percent
- item_id

An item can have more than one tax

I want to write a query that will give me all items with no tax. This query needs to be as fast as possible.

I was thinking

```
select id from Item where Id NOT in (select item_id from Item_taxes)
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id 
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN item_taxes on item.id=item_taxes.item_id 
WHERE item_taxes.item_id IS NULL
```

### EDIT

Please refer to to the comment by @ypercube as it adds more explanation and clarification.

Comment: Why is this better than the OP's query?

Comment: In some MySQL versions, sub-queries has poor performance, while they are still logically correct. Here is an interesting discussion about this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Comment: There are several different types of suqbueries (derived tables, uncorrelated subqueries, uncorrelated ones, etc). I know some of them have (had) efficiency issues with previous versions of MySQL but not all. The `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` for example is usually quite efficient. In recent versions (like 5.6, 5.7 and Mariadb 5.3+) there have been several improvements to the optimizer, so the "subqueries have poor performance" claim is even less valid. But feel free to add your explanations on the answer, that's why I commented. An answer with only code is not what we are aiming here, at DBA.SE.

Comment: And here is another great (although not recent) article and tests on the [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost create an index on the Id columns on both tables then do

> Select id from item i left outer join Item_taxes it on i.id = id.id where id.id is null